# Lost connect to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have an Innodb database which have a big table with many rows. Once I'm trying to access the data or run any query(like "check table_name") against this specific table mysql crashes(restarts) and I'm getting the error:
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

I have already tried to increase max_packetsize and the net_timeouts flags.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Edit:

Crash log:

```
2022-12-30T16:25:56.676880Z 208 [ERROR] InnoDB: In pages [page id: space=372, pa                                                                         ge number=11135] and [page id: space=372, page number=11136] of index `GEN_CLUST                                                                         _INDEX` of table `SHAS_2015_NEW`.`b_media_21_646_0000_11925`
InnoDB: broken FIL_PAGE_NEXT or FIL_PAGE_PREV links
2022-12-30T16:25:56.676925Z 208 [ERROR] InnoDB: In pages [page id: space=372, pa                                                                         ge number=11135] and [page id: space=372, page number=11136] of index `GEN_CLUST                                                                         _INDEX` of table `SHAS_2015_NEW`.`b_media_21_646_0000_11925`
InnoDB: 'compact' flag mismatch
2022-12-30T16:25:56.676936Z 208 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page index id 0 != data dictiona                                                                         ry index id 577
2022-12-30 18:25:56 0x7fa1384e9700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 14033041                                                                         1136768 in file btr0btr.cc line 4710
InnoDB: Failing assertion: !page_is_empty(page) || (level == 0 && page_get_page_                                                                         no(page) == dict_index_get_page(index))
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
16:25:56 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 76388 K  b                                                                         ytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fa0f81dd110
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fa1384e8e70 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xe8e68b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x36f)[0x77524f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7fa67f45d390]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7fa67e816438]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7fa67e81803a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x74a77c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x10dd73d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z18btr_validate_indexP12dict_index_tPK5trx_tb+0x264)[0x10dec34                                                                         ]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN11ha_innobase5checkEP3THDP15st_ha_check_opt+0x278)[0xf2a378]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler8ha_checkEP3THDP15st_ha_check_opt+0x7b)[0x7cd71b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xdb48f4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN19Sql_cmd_check_table7executeEP3THD+0x97)[0xdb5497]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x2160)[0xc42570]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDP12Parser_state+0x3dd)[0xc473ad]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_commandP3THDPK8COM_DATA19enum_server_command+0x11a                                                                         0)[0xc48610]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x1c7)[0xc49ae7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_connection+0x290)[0xd0e140]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x1b4)[0xeb03e4]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7fa67f4536ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fa67e8e851d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7fa0f8072240): check table b_media_21_646_0000_11925
Connection ID (thread ID): 208
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2022-12-30T16:25:56.970335Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (re                                                                         quested 5000)
2022-12-30T16:25:56.970397Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (r                                                                         equested 2000)
2022-12-30T16:25:57.145883Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is                                                                          deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see doc                                                                         umentation for more details).
2022-12-30T16:25:57.148901Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16                                                                         .04.1-log) starting as process 9454 ...
2022-12-30T16:25:57.153242Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2022-12-30T16:25:57.153267Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic                                                                          builtins
2022-12-30T16:25:57.153272Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-12-30T16:25:57.153276Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence()                                                                          is used for memory barrier
2022-12-30T16:25:57.153283Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2022-12-30T16:25:57.153286Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-12-30T16:25:57.153526Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-12-30T16:25:57.153643Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2022-12-30T16:25:57.155093Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total siz                                                                         e = 20G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2022-12-30T16:25:58.482523Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer                                                                          pool
2022-12-30T16:25:58.719968Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is aut                                                                         horized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpri                                                                         ority().
2022-12-30T16:25:58.744995Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Ba                                                                         rracuda.
2022-12-30T16:25:58.915826Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkp                                                                         oint lsn 10408206134578
2022-12-30T16:25:58.915857Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log s                                                                         equence number 10408206134587
2022-12-30T16:25:58.915862Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2022-12-30T16:25:58.915872Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2022-12-30T16:25:59.270028Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 1                                                                         862900, file name mysql-bin.000001
2022-12-30T16:26:00.014203Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-12-30T16:26:00.014242Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-12-30T16:26:00.014281Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-12-30T16:26:00.075009Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-12-30T16:26:00.076863Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-12-30T16:26:00.076904Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-12-30T16:26:00.077640Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-12-30T16:26:00.127880Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.33 started; log sequence number 10408206134587
2022-12-30T16:26:00.128095Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-12-30T16:26:00.128605Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2022-12-30T16:26:00.138272Z 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin
2022-12-30T16:26:00.138325Z 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2022-12-30T16:26:00.138384Z 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
```

If I'm Using select with Limit statement then I can select up to 681,000 rows

Comment: You need to check the server's error log to see why it's crashing. It sounds like it may be running out of memory to process the big query.

Comment: It could be due to a variety of reasons. First check error MySQL error log. if you are using PHP script you may need to configuration PHP. like: memory_limit, max_execution_time

Comment: Hey, Sorry. I though I was posting the crash log from the sql error log. It is now in the comments.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.